# Unity3d AppRequest invite limit on select

Tags: c#, facebook, unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

I have problem with `FB.AppRequest`. I need the user to only select one friend from the list shown in the Facebook UI, but I can't find a way to do it looking at the Facebook Unity3d SDK.

Thanks for the help.

```
public void ShareWithUsers()
{
    FB.AppRequest(

        "Come and join me, i bet u cant beat my score",
        null,
        new List<object>() {"app_users"},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        ShareWithUsersCallback

    );
}

void ShareWithUsersCallback(IAppRequestResult result)
{   
    if (result.Cancelled)
    {
        Debug.Log("Challenge Cancel");
        GameObject.Find("CallBacks").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Challenge Cancel";
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Challenge on error");
        GameObject.Find("CallBacks").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Challenge on error";
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.RawResult))
    {
        Debug.Log("Success on challenge");

    }
}
```

Comment: Check how you are writing "challenge" and "success" in your code, and you might want to consider writing all the debug logs with the same format like: `Challenge Cancel`, `Challenge Error` and `Challenge Success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [FB.AppRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest) it explains that the fourth parameter is the "to".

```
public static void AppRequest(
    string message, 
    OGActionType actionType,
    string objectId,
    IEnumerable<string> to,
    string data = "",
    string title = "",    
    FacebookDelegate<IAppRequestResult> callback = null
)
```

Where `to` is a list of Facebook IDs to which to send the request, if you leave it `null` like now the sender will be shown a dialog allowing him/her to choose the recipients.

So in your case you can leave it `null` and let the user choose, or if it has already chosen (you already know which friend he wants to challenge) then you will need to create a list and add his Facebook ID.

```
FB.AppRequest(

        "Come and join me, i bet u cant beat my score",
        null,
        new List<object>() {"app_users"},
        new List<string>() {"[id of your friend]"},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        ShareWithUsersCallback

    );
```

Either way this line `new List<object>() {"app_users"}` means that the request can be sended to someone who already plays the game. But if you remove it it could be send to any of his friends.

I have seen [some older code](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/716501/facebook-sdk-unity-invite.html) that set a `maxRecipients` which would allow you, if setted to one, to be sure that the user selects only one friend through the UI:

```
FB.AppRequest(
        string message,
        IEnumerable<string> to = null,
        IEnumerable<object> filters = null,
        IEnumerable<string> excludeIds = null,
        int? maxRecipients = null,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",
        FacebookDelegate<IAppRequestResult> callback = null);
```

But this no longer appears in the documentation.